# Implementing U-Net for pixel value-based cell segmentation in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, unet-neural-network

So I recently started using Pytorch and have been given the task to segment a cell into it's 12 classes based on pixel values. I was wondering if could use U-Net for such a task and if so, would I have to implement it from scratch? And furthermore, I have trouble understanding how to train models in PyTorch.

I have tried googling for information but so far have found very little or nothing of use.